# Save temp folder

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I save the current temp folder without looking for it in the temp folder? I mean, each activity is logging in the temp or saving some session. So, I want to use the temp folder that I saved as a user agent. I know how to use but I don't know how to save without looking for it in temp.

An example:

```
import os
listx=os.listdir(path='C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp')
for i in listx:
    if "some_folder_name" in i:
       if len(os.listdir(path='C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/'+i))==0:
           print("empty",i)
       else:
           print("not empty",i)
```

I used it here to save the current temp folder by copying it to another location instead of printing the screen.

Comment: Either you have temporary data and save it in a random new folder, or your data is not temporary and should be stored somewhere else.

Comment: How does the question relates to _Selenium_?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I am using selenium to login with User-agent without login manually.